# Changing UIButton borderColor in sync with title when highlighting

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrol

I have a custom *UIButton* with a border. I'd like the `layer.borderColor` to be in sync with the `titleLabel` when the button reacts to the user events - i.e. becomes *Highlighted* or *Selected*.

Sometimes these events are animated with a delay, sometimes immediately.

E.g.:
Tap & Hold the button - Immediately
Release the button - With animation

How to make the button's border replicate the same behavior? How to track transitions between the *UIControlStates*?

I.e. the decision on whether to animate the border depends on the transition:
`Normal` -> `Highlighted` - no animation
`Highlighted` -> `Normal` - with animation

How can I detect such transitions?

Here is the code for the button which doesn't address the event of moving the finger out of bounds, but otherwise works good:

```
import UIKit

final class BorderButton: UIButton {
  override var isEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {
      updateBorderColor()
    }
  }

  override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
      updateBorderColor(animated: false)
    }
  }

  override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
      let animated = !isHighlighted
      updateBorderColor(animated: animated)
    }
  }

  override func tintColorDidChange() {
    super.tintColorDidChange()
    updateBorderColor()
  }

  private func updateBorderColor(animated: Bool = false) {
    var color: UIColor = tintColor
    if !isEnabled || tintAdjustmentMode == .dimmed {
      color = dimmedTintColor()
    } else if isHighlighted {
      color = lightColor()
    }

    if animated {
      let current = layer.borderColor ?? UIColor.clear.cgColor
      let cgColor = color.cgColor
      borderColorAnimation(from: current, to: cgColor, duration: 0.4)
    } else {
      layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    }
  }


  private func borderColorAnimation(from: CGColor, to: CGColor, duration: CFTimeInterval) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.fromValue = from
    animation.toValue = to
    animation.duration = duration
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "borderColor")
    layer.borderColor = to
  }

  private func lightColor() -> UIColor {
    var hue: CGFloat = 0, saturation: CGFloat = 0, brightness: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
    tintColor.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)
    return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha * 0.2)
  }

  private func dimmedTintColor() -> UIColor {
    var hue: CGFloat = 0, brightness: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
    tintColor.getHue(&hue, saturation: nil, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)
    return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 0, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
  }
}
```

Comment: You're talking a `UIButton` and wanting to detect when a user "moves a finger out of bounds"? Have you tried coding for a `.touchUpOutside` action?

Comment: May I know your goals for this?

Comment: @Glenn to create a unified experience of a "rounded" button, so that the border reacts similarly to the label of the button.